# how to enable Pinch to zoom in CPTGraph hosting view in brief

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I had created one graph using CPTGraphhosting view.and i want to enable user can pinch and zoom the graph.i am wondering from lot of documentation but there is no valuable answers for core plot CPTGraph hosting view.
Can anyone share brief guidance on this condition.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `allowsUserInteraction` on the plot space to enable zooming and scrolling. You can turn off pinch gestures (leaving the scrolling active) with the hosting view property called `allowPinchScaling`.

There are lots of examples in the example apps included with Core Plot. For example:

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks Eric for fast response but its not working for my graph.there is no effects i used `self.advancesHostingView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;` can you explain in detailing?

Comment: i am using CPTXYGraph for graph.